# How to use boost::async() with an executor wrapper generated by a scheduler?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread

With the following code:

```
boost::basic_thread_pool e;
boost::scheduler<Clock> scheduler;
auto wrapper = scheduler.on(e);

// test run after

auto executorAfter2Seconds = wrapper.after(boost::chrono::seconds(2));
boost::async(executorAfter2Seconds, []() { return 10; }); // leads to an error: no member named 'try_executing_one' in boost::executors::resubmit_at_executor<....>
```

I get the error of the comment. When I call the submit manually, passing a promise and setting the value of a future:

```
boost::promise<int> p0;
auto f0 = p0.get_future();
executorAfter2Seconds.submit([&p0](){ p0.set_value(10); });
```

it works without problems. How can I passed a scheduled executor to boost::async()?